# keeping the inputted value at is if form is submitted with codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

This is my login form:

```
     <div class="form-container">
        <h1 style="text-align:left">Login Here!</h1><br>
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/User_Authentication_Controller/login_user" method="POST">
          <div class="error_msg1"></div>
          <input autofocus="autofocus" type="text" name="txt_login_username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username.."/><div class="error_msg2"></div>
          <input type="password" name="txt_login_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password.." /><div class="error_msg3"></div>
          <center><button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Login</button><br/><br/>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Pages_Controller/show_forgotpassword">Forgot Password?</a></center>
        </form>
    </div>
```

This is my controller:

```
public function login_user(){
    $username = $this->input->post('txt_login_username');
    $password = md5($this->input->post('txt_login_password'));
    $result=$this->LogIn_Model->login($username,$password);

    if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
    if($result!=null){
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
        $_SESSION["id"] = $result["0"]["Account_no"];
        $_SESSION["Usertype"] = $result["0"]["Usertype"];
        if($result["0"]["Status"] == 1){
            if($result["0"]["Usertype"] == 0){
                redirect('User_Authentication_Controller');
            }
            else if($result["0"]["Usertype"] == 1){
                redirect('Pages_Controller/show_adminpage/');           
            }
        }
        else if($result["0"]["Status"] == 0){
            redirect('User_Authentication_Controller');             
        }
    }
    else{
        redirect('User_Authentication_Controller');
    }
   }
   else{
        redirect('User_Authentication_Controller'); 
   } 

}
```

This actually works!

Now my question is:

As you see in the `else if($result["0"]["Status"] == 0){}`, all I want is that after I submitted the page it will redirect back to the login, and I want that the

```
   <div class="error_msg1"></div>
```

will show an error telling, "Your account has been deactivated by the Admin" And if he inputs a username it will stay still as he submit it! how will I do that? If he inputs Username: Michael and Inputs a wrong password, I want the Username: Michael to stay still! How will I do that after the form submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Way 1

Use `AJAX` instead of `form`. Your js make an ajax post to your server, and then get the result. Depending on it, your js reacts, for example, showing error messages. This is a good choice.

#### Way 2

For example, you can set `$_SESSION['ShowErrorMsg1']=true` in login_user, then in your login page php, just say:

.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['ShowErrorMsg1']) && $_SESSION['ShowErrorMsg1']==true){
    echo '<div class="error_msg1"></div>';
}
```

then the error msg will be shown.

**UPDATE:**

The main idea is that you can storage *anything* you want to pass it from one php to another php in `$_SESSION`. If you want to pass on `$msg_content` for example, just use `$_SESSION['somekey']=$msg_content;` in one php. Then in another php use `$_SESSION['somekey']` who storages the data of `$msg_content`.

Comment: I like the another way, because i do not know how to use AJax yet! but my question is how will i get the error_msg1? bcoz it is in class, and if I change the class to name, i still cant get the value bcoz the type is not an input it is a div! how will I put that in login_user?

Comment: Thanks mate! now I really get it! $_SESSION is very useful man! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

you can use set_userdata to store error msg and can show:
in your controller:

```
else if($result["0"]["Status"] == 0){
$this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg1','Some Error Msg!'); 
}
```

and in your view:

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('error_msg1')) : ?>
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <span class="alert-rr">
        <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="alert-msg">
        <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error_msg1'); ?>
    </span>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```